# After installing Resharper Solution Explorer in VS 2013 during renaming selects all file name (with extension)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

Before installing Resharper Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 during renaming selected file name without extension. And it was very convenient and greate. But after installing Resharper Solution Explorer in VS 2013 during renaming selects all file name (with extension).
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a ReSharper issue - at least (and I hate to say it) it works on my machine. With or without ReSharper installed, when I rename a file, it selects only the name portion of the filename, not the extension.

Perhaps it's another extension that's causing the issue? You could try running `devenv.exe /safemode` to see if it is another extension, then you'll need to selectively disable extensions until you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, after restarting VS this problem vanished. So it is some kind of VS or Resharper bugs, perhaps... If this problem will occure again I'l try command you suggested. Thanks!